# Macroeconomic effects. Effects of a time serie on another

Tags: time-series, forecasting, macroeconomics, effects

I have a monthly time series for the provision in a financial institution. Take real data until december 2017 and predict it with a Bat model until June 2018 using R and I have an error of 0.12%. This is really great. Now I need to see the macroeconomic effects in my series, For example how the GDP or the external interest rate affects my provision series. How can I measure that impact? How can I find or calculate the impact of one series on another? to evaluate how this exogenous variable (GDP) affects my Provision serie or in others words how my forecast will be affected by the GDP Serie.

Comment: Follow Tucker's advice: make graphs. As many graphs as you can.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: use a regression. You can model the dependency in many ways, for instance you can fit a VAR model.

Since you already have preferences for `R`, you can read the vignette of the package `vars`. Here is the [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf) to the pdf.

Following this approach, suppose that your variable of interest (provision) is denoted $P_t$ and the two macroeconomic variables that will play the role of the 'exogenous' variables, namely GDP and interest rates, are denoted $GDP_t$ and $r_t$, respectively. Then if $y_t=(P_t,GDP_t,r_t))\in\mathbb{R}^3$, the VAR(p) process is defined as

$$
\mathbf{y}_t=\mathbf{A}_1\mathbf{y}_{t-1}+\dots+\mathbf{A}_p\mathbf{y}_{t-p}+\mathbf{u}_t
$$
where $\mathbf{A}_j$ would be the matrix containing the coefficients for all $j=1,\dots,p$, and $\mathbf{u}_t\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector such that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{u}_t)=\mathbf{0}$ and variance-covariance matrix $\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{u}_t)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{u}_t\mathbf{u}_t')=\Sigma_u$.